# Can not read property 'UserName' of undefined angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I tried many solutions out there but none of them helped me to solve this ...
Can't figure out what is the problem in my code ...

**HTML CODE ::**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Please Enter Your Username" [(ngModel)]="currentUser.UserName" minlength="3" required id="userNameBox" name="UserName" #uName="ngModel">
```

**COMPONENT CODE ::**

```
    profile() {
        let uid = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('id'));
        this._homeService.profile(uid).subscribe(
            res => {
            this.currentUser = res

                console.log(this.currentUser);

});
```

**SERVICE ::**

```
profile(id: number) {

        return this._http.get(url, id).map(
            (res: Response) => {
                console.log(res.json())
                return new User(res.json()

                ) }
        ).catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**MODEL ::**

```
export class User {

constructor(json: any) {
    if (json != null) {
        this.Id = json.Id;
        this.UserName = json.UserName;
        this.FirstName = json.FirstName;
        this.LastName = json.LastName;
        this.Gender = json.Gender;
        this.Password = json.Password;
        this.Email = json.Email;
    }

}

Id: number = 0;
UserName: string = "";
FirstName: string = "";
LastName: string = "";
Gender: string = "";
Password: string = "";
Email: string = "";
```

}

Comment: I tried it earlier but getting this error        ::
Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: The '?.' operator cannot be used in the assignment at column 23 in [currentUser?.UserName=$event]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are using `[(ngModel)]` :

You have to do it like this , **you can't use** `safe operator ?` with `2 way data binding` :

```
<div *ngIf="currentUser.UserName">
     <input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Please Enter Your Username" [(ngModel)]="currentUser.UserName" minlength="3" required id="userNameBox" name="UserName" #uName="ngModel">
</div>
```

**OR**

Create intial object with default properties:

```
this.currentUser = { 
                        'UserName' : '',
                        'Email' : '',
                        // other properties , that you are using on template side 
                    }
```

Here is the link to the working demo of second method :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-initial-value

Comment: I already tried second one with default properties set in model like this ..

export class User {

    constructor(json: any) {
        if (json != null) {
            this.Id = json.Id;
            this.UserName = json.UserName;
            this.FirstName = json.FirstName;

        }

    }

    Id: number = 0;
    UserName: string = "";
    FirstName: string = "";

}

Comment: Viveks answer is correct. Main problem is that your model is loaded before the data is rendered from service and it is undefined by that time. Try instantize it inside of callback function of service.

Comment: Please try my code in your code you are not assigning values to `currentUser` , put my code inside constrcutor and it will work.

Comment: @Aarsh, I have shown 2 methods you can use any of that , both will work 100%;

Comment: see i have code in constructor like this >>>         this.currentUser = new User(null);  >>> so it is same as you are telling me to do see my model code

Comment: @VivekDoshi , in my last project i have same code that working but in this project it's not. and i  tried your solution it's working but still in console  I am getting array with  all the properties is undefined

Comment: Will you up my que ??